# Instagram API Permission declined Magento Extension

Tags: magento, instagram, instagram-api

We already have Instagram Magento extensions, the extension fetches images from the account we configure in the backend and shows in frontend side of Magento wherever i want. It was working fine until Instagram declared new API permission review system. I tried submitting app 2-3 times now, everytime declined. Is there anybody can help to get my app approved. 
If it won't work many extension vendors will have problem with it. Instgram guys shall help but even they are not replying.

Comment: WIthout any authentication  https://magecomp.com/magento-instagram-connect.html

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this extension** 
I am also using this extension it's working fine for me and it will definitely work for you also

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/instagram-integration-widget-by-neklo.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, figured out another extension which don't need to submit the app and can fetch the images directly from instagram without any API details,
https://magecomp.com/magento-instagram-connect.html